# selecting multiple columns with where clause in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

A student studies more than 1 optional subject. I have created two columns named optional_sub1 and optional_sub2. I want to select only one column from two using sql statement. 
SQL statement is as under:

```
$sql= "SELECT * 
       FROM students 
       WHERE class = '$SelectClass' 
       && optional_sub1 = '$SelectSubject' 
       || optional_sub2 = '$SelectSubject'";
```

Please modify the above syntax.
Thanks.

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection! Always parameterise your queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE `AND/OR` for `&&/||` operator respectively

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM students WHERE class = '$SelectClass' 
and (optional_sub1 = '$SelectSubject' or optional_sub2 = '$SelectSubject')"
```

Comment: Worked for me. thanks alot. but if i want to add optional_sub3 also, can i use  $sql= "SELECT * FROM students WHERE class = '$SelectClass' 
and (optional_sub1 = '$SelectSubject' or optional_sub2 = '$SelectSubject' or optional_sub3 = '$SelectSubject')"

Comment: @Akhtar, yes you can

Answer (score 0):

Use AND/OR instead of C#/Java operators.

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM students 
       WHERE class = '$SelectClass' 
             and (optional_sub1 = '$SelectSubject' 
                  or 
                  optional_sub2 = '$SelectSubject'");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM students 
WHERE class = '$SelectClass' 
and optional_sub1 = '$SelectSubject' 
and optional_sub2 = '$SelectSubject';
```

Comment: `optional_sub1 = '$SelectSubject' and optional_sub2 = '$SelectSubject'` is not in OP's requirements and this propably will result in empty resultset